# RxJs operators causing typescript errors

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-cli

**Working version**:

```
   const observable = Observable
      .from([Promise.resolve('1'), Promise.resolve('2')])
      .subscribe((results) => {})
```

**Broken version** (added `mergeAll` operator):

```
const observable = Observable
  .from([Promise.resolve('1'), Promise.resolve('2')])
  .mergeAll()
  .subscribe((results) => {})
```

> Propery '**subscribe**' doesn't exist on type '**Promise<{string}>**'

I'm using the basic `Angular CLI` setup.

What might be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are returning the resolving the promise. You should be using **fromPromise** operator as below

```
const observable = Observable
  .fromPromise([Promise.resolve('1'), Promise.resolve('2')])
  .mergeAll()
  .subscribe(results => console.log(results));
```

Also try logging the results as in the code.